# jslinq with dynamic where condition and or operator

Tags: javascript, jslinq

I have used jslinq (i.e http://jslinq.codeplex.com/) to filter my json data.

The following code is used to get the values statically

```
var whereExample1 = JSLINQ(myList).Where(function(item){
    return (item.FirstName == "Chris") || (item.FirstName == "Test")  
});
```

**But I have a problem while making it dynamic**

```
var names=["Chris","Test"];
 var whereExample1 = JSLINQ(myList).Where(function(item){ return 
  for(i=0;i<=names.length;i++)
  {
         if(i == names.length)
         {
              item.FirstName == names[i];
         }
         else
         {
            item.FirstName == names[i]+'||';    
         }
  }    
});
```

But I couldn't able to make the desired output.Please help me